# $this.data(...) is undefined. How to debug?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm quite new to web programming. I'm using the Bootstrap DateTimePicker module in an single-page application, and anytime I inject some HTML onto the page referencing the DateTimePicker, I get the following error message in Firefox/Firebug.

```
    TypeError: $this.data(...) is undefined.      jquery->...eval(line 24, col 6)
```

The DateTimePicker component works but always generates this error.

HTML (Jade)

```
    .datetimepicker.input-group.date.mb-sm(data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD",data-pick-time="false")
      input#accdd.form-control(type='text',value=(child.dob),size="8")
      span.input-group-addon
        span.fa.fa-calendar
    script(src='app/js/dtp.js')
```

Here's the script that I have to include every time I need to use the component. That's another question I have. Why do I need to include this code each time I use the DateTimePicker component? This is all loaded at startup, but I need to include this each time I inject new HTML with this component.

```
(function($, window, document){
  'use strict';

  var Selector = '.datetimepicker';

  $(Selector).each(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        options = $this.data(); // allow to set options via data-* attributes

    $this.datetimepicker($.extend(
      options,
      { // support for FontAwesome icons
        icons: {
            time:   'fa fa-clock-o',
            date:   'fa fa-calendar',
            up:     'fa fa-arrow-up',
            down:   'fa fa-arrow-down'
        }
      }));

    // Force a dropdown hide when click out of the input
    $(document).on('click', function(){
      $this.data('DateTimePicker').hide();
    });
  });

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

So it looks like the error is coming from the line:

```
      $this.data('DateTimePicker').hide();
```

I can't for the life of me figure-out how I would go about debugging this issue.

Here's the Firebug console of the bug. First invocation works fine, subsequent invocations generate errors. Strange that errors are generated before function is called (I added 'Why oh why' message as 1st line of function).

[image: Firebug console]

Comment: Can you show your relevant code please? Impossible to guess what's going on.

Comment: @JoshBeam Done. Thanks.